# What is the lexical and syntactic analysis during the process of compiling in C Compiler?

Tags: c, parsing, compilation, preprocessor, lexical-analysis

What is the lexical and syntactic analysis during the process of compiling. Does the preprocessing happens after lexical and syntactic analysis ?

Comment: What language are you talking about?  Please add the relevant tag.

Comment: Preprocessing happens before the linking is done. All macros are substituted before it is compiled.

Comment: @squiguy Lexing and Parsing and Compiling happens before the Linking is done ... so ... what's that supposed to mean? :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
     int a = 10;
     if (a < 4)
     {
          printf("%d", a);
     }
```

In the **Lexical Analysis** phase: You identify each word/token and assign a meaning to it.
In the code above, you start by identifying that **i** followed by **n** followed by **t** and then a space is the word **int**, and that it is a language keyword;**1** followed by **0** and a space is a number **10** and so on.

In the **Syntactic Analysis** phase: You verify whether the code follows the language syntax(grammar rules). For example, you check whether there is only one variable on the LHS of an operator(considering language C), that each statement is terminated by a **;**, that **if** is followed by a conditional/Boolean statement etc.

Like others have mentioned, usually, preprocessing happens before lexical analysis or syntactical analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Lexical analysis happens **BEFORE** the syntactical analysis. This is logical because when it is necessary to call a macro it is necessary to identify the borders of an identifier first. This is done with lexical analysis. After that syntactical analysis kicks in. Note that compilers are typically not generating the full preprocessed source before starting the syntactic analysis. They read the source picking one lexema at a time, do the preprocessing if needed, and feed the result to syntactic analysis.

In one case lexical analysis happens twice. This is the paste buffering. Look at the code:

```
#define En(x) Abcd ## x ## x

enum En(5)
{
    a, b = 20, c, d
};
```

This code defines enum with a name `Abcd55`. When the `##` are processed during the macro expansion, the data is placed into an internal buffer. After that this buffer is scanned much like a small #include. During the scanning compiler will break contents of the buffer into lexemas. It may happen that borders of scanned lexemas will not match the borders of original lexemas that were placed into the buffer. In the example above 3 lexemas are placed into the buffer but only one is retrieved.

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'lexemes'? 'Lexemas' is Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessing happens before the lexical analysis iirc
Comments get filtered out, #define, ... and after that, a compiler generates tokens with a scanner/lexer (lexical analysis). After that compilers generate parsetrees, which are for the syntactic analysis

Comment: "Preprocessing happens before the lexical analysis iirc Comments get filtered out, .." thanks for this info !

Comment: If you wanna compare it to a natural language, preprocessing is getting the text in. From a paper, of a screen. Your filtering things like pictures, ... . After that you get the words, which is the lexical analysis. You're looking for words which are in a lexicon. After that you do the syntax, thats how the sentence is build, grammar, ... .

Answer (score 0):

There are exceptions, but it usually breaks out like this:

- Preprocess - transform program text to program text
- Lexical analysis - transform program text to "tokens", which are essentially small integers with attributes attached
- Syntactic analysis - transform program text to abstract syntax

The definition of "abstract syntax" can vary.  In one-pass compilers, abstract syntax amounts to tartget code.  But theses days it's usually a tree or DAG that logically represents the structure of the program.

Answer (score 0):

When we are talking about C programming language, we should note that there is an ISO (ANSI) stadard for the language. Here is a last public draft of C99 (ISO/IEC 9899:1999): www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf

There is a section "5.1.1.2 Translation phases" which says how should C program be parsed. There are stages:

... some steps for multi-byte, trigraph and backslash processing...

> 3). The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens and sequences of
>   white-space characters (including comments).

This is lexical analysis for preprocessing. Only preprocessor directives, punctuation, string constants, identifiers, comments are lexed here.

> 4). Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded

This is preprocessing itself. This phase will also include files from `#include` and then it will delete preprocessing directives (like `#define` or `#ifdef` and  other)

... processing of string literals...

> 7). White-space characters separating tokens are no longer significant. Each
>   preprocessing token is converted into a token. The resulting tokens are
>   syntactically and semantically analyzed and translated as a translation unit.

Conversion to token means language keyword detection and constants detection.
This is the step of final lexical analysis; syntactic and semantic analyses.

So, your question was:

> Does the preprocessing happens after lexical and syntactic analysis ?

Some lexical analysis is needed to do preprocessing, so order is:
lexical_for_preprocessor, preprocessing, true_lexical, other_analysis.

PS: Real C compiler may be organized in slightly different way, but it *must* behave in the same way as written in standard.